# How to build a function to return the nearest number from a set of -unstored numbers?

Tags: statistics

I need to build a function that given a number it either returns the number within the set (not stored) or returns an approximation of the possible highest and lowest number within the set for the given input.

For example the following is the set of numbers. This set is not stored so the function should be created when this set is created.

> Set = {1, 2, 10, 15, 20, 31, 50, 90, 101, 200}

If input = 20. Output should be 20

If input = 25. Output should be 20 (lowest) and 31 (highest).

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to perform this computation?

Comment: What do you mean by "possible" ? You could just define the following:
Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the set of sets of real numbers of size $n$. Then, when set $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
f_A: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n: f_A(x) =
\left\{
\begin{split}
(x), & ~\text{if } x \in A \\
(\max{A}, \min{A}),& ~\text{otherwise}
\end{split}
\right.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by not stored?

Comment: @angryavian - Yes. An algorithm or a function.

Comment: @MattiP - By possible I mean that the function does it's best to return the nearest highest and lowest number from the set.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - By not stored I meant that after the function is created the set is not stored anywhere in-memory (RAM or disk) so the function should do it's best in returning the output.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is more of a programming question than mathematics question. From a mathematical point of view, it's not difficult to just define this kind of function.